# CSS Progress bar with a circle dot at the end

Tags: html, css

I know this question have been asked a couple of times before. But I want to achieve this kind of design:

[image]

So far this is what I found this in codepen:

https://codepen.io/alvaromontoro/pen/LYjZqzP

HTML:

```
<div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="--value:80"></div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes growProgressBar {
  0%, 33% { --pgPercentage: 0; }
  100% { --pgPercentage: var(--value); }
}

@property --pgPercentage {
  syntax: '<number>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
}

div[role="progressbar"] {
  --size: 12rem;
  --fg: #369;
  --bg: #def;
  --pgPercentage: var(--value);
  animation: growProgressBar 3s 1 forwards;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(closest-side, white 80%, transparent 0 99.9%, white 0),
    conic-gradient(var(--fg) calc(var(--pgPercentage) * 1%), var(--bg) 0)
    ;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: calc(var(--size) / 5);
  color: var(--fg);
}

div[role="progressbar"]::before {
  counter-reset: percentage var(--value);
  content: counter(percentage) '%';
}

/* demo */
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: So your question is how to replace the percentage number in the middle with an image of a kettle?

Comment: I can manage putting the kettle image, my issue is how do I add the dot at the end of the progress bar.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far - how are you drawing that circle and how are you positioning it? Have a go - you could consider using a pseudo after element perhaps so it remains as just a visual embellishment rather than part of the DOM.

Comment: I already posted it in the details. Of all the CSS progress bar I searched, this is the most usable thing that I found. Here I can put the percentage I want in the HTML then it will reflect in the frontend. I'm not much of a CSS expert here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful if you could go through the code to understand what it is doing so far.

Notice that the way it is animating that bar is simply by animating one CSS variable - the percentage which goes from 0 to what is to be shown eventually.

In the code you already have this is used to draw a conic gradient with an angle which increases from 0 to that percentage of 360degrees.

We can use the same idea to move an element as if it were the hand of a clock, rotating it about the middle of its bottom in sync with the growing of the conic gradient.

First let's draw the 'hand' of the clock in the upright position. We can use a CSS pseudo after element to do this - as it's purely a visual embellishment we don't want to add actual content to the DOM. It's shown in pink here.

And to get the circle we give it a radial-gradient background image.

[image]

Now we want to rotate it about its bottom central point (the middle of the circle) so we change its transform origin and set it to have a rotation which depends on the CSS property (variable) which holds the percentage value we are already animating.

```css
@keyframes growProgressBar {
  0%,
  33% {
    --pgPercentage: 0;
  }
  100% {
    --pgPercentage: var(--value);
  }
}

@property --pgPercentage {
  syntax: '<number>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
}

div[role="progressbar"] {
  --size: 12rem;
  --fg: #369;
  --bg: #def;
  --pgPercentage: var(--value);
  animation: growProgressBar 3s 1 forwards;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: radial-gradient(closest-side, white 80%, transparent 0 99.9%, white 0), conic-gradient(var(--fg) calc(var(--pgPercentage) * 1%), var(--bg) 0);
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: calc(var(--size) / 5);
  color: var(--fg);
  position: relative;
}

div[role="progressbar"]::before {
  counter-reset: percentage var(--value);
  content: counter(percentage) '%';
}

div[role="progressbar"]::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(var(--size) / 2 + 10px);
  width: calc(10 / 100 * var(--size) + 20px);
  top: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(calc(var(--pgPercentage) / 100 * 360deg));
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  animation: growProgressBar 3s 1 forwards;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: radial-gradient(var(--fg) 0 50%, transparent 50% 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 0;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
}


/* demo */

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="--value:80"></div>
```

Note, in the snippet just for the demo I've added px values to the width. You will probably want to look closely at your use case perhaps to define the extra in terms of % to make it more flexible/responsive.

Comment: how much time it took to make this?

Comment: @Ashishsah not sure why you want to know, but a few minutes (I don't answer questions with code if I can't do it over a cup of coffee....).

Comment: Just wanted to know... Basically, I just wasted an hour on it -_-